# In scalaz-stream, how can i run a task when a Sink is terminated?

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

I have copied an example from http4s:

```
// Print received Text frames, and, on completion, notify the console
  val sink: Sink[Task, WebSocketFrame] = Process.constant {
    case Text(t) => Task.delay(println(t))
    case f       => Task.delay(println(s"Unknown type: $f"))
  }.onComplete(Process.eval[Task, Nothing](Task{println("Terminated!")}).drain)
```

This yields a compilation error: "Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type _A"

I just want to printline "Terminated!" when the sink gets terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you remove the types from the `Process.eval` call:

```
... .onComplete(Process.eval(Task{println("Terminated!")}).drain)
```

The problem here is that your `Process.eval` call constructs a `Process[Task, Unit]` and not a `Process[Task, Nothing]` as you ask for by giving the types explicity. Calling `drain` converts the `Process[Task, Unit]` to a `Process[Task, Nothing]` afterwards.

**Update:** Here is an example of a sink that performs some side effect on completion:

```
scala> val sink = io.stdOutLines.onComplete(Process.eval_(Task(println("END"))))
sink: scalaz.stream.Process[[x]scalaz.concurrent.Task[x],String => scalaz.concurrent.Task[Unit]] = Append(Emit(Vector(<function1>)),Vector(<function1>, <function1>))

scala> Process("a", "b", "c").toSource.to(sink).run.run
a
b
c
END
```

Comment: or you can even use `onComplete(eval_(/* your task */))`. Note using of `eval_` instead of `eval`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that leaves me with ```Expression of type Process[Any,Nothin] doesn't conform to expected type stream.Sink[Task,WebsocketBits.WebSocketFrame]```

Comment: @Atle try to break up your sink into two `val`s and maybe add type annotations to them. The process you pass to `onComplete` should be of type `Process[Task, Nothing]`.

Comment: i have refactored out the "completing" process into `val p :Process[Task,Nothing]`, the compiler still emits the same error

Comment: When i split out the _onComplete_ call like this `val p: Process[Task, Nothing] = Process.eval(Task {println("Terminated!")}).drain
      val sink: Sink[Task, WebSocketFrame] = Process.constant {
        case Text(t, x) => Task.delay(println(t))
        case f => Task.delay(println(s"Unknown type: $f"))
      }

      val sinkWithComplete:Sink[Task, WebSocketFrame] = sink.onComplete(p)`it works